# Thumbnails in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to show thumbnails of Sharepoint Online images on my website, to avoid downloading all images beforehand.

Is it possible to make Sharepoint Online (Office365) automatically create thumbnails (user defined size) of images that you upload?
Or is it possible to make SO scale the image before download, by url parameters?

/Bo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thumbnails can be generated using the [Image Rendition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj720398.aspx) feature. This feature exists both online and in the on-prem product. Turning on renditions is pretty straight forward.

1. Go to the site settings page (in the gear)
2. Click on Manage Site Features
3. Activate "SharePoint Server Publishing"

Once the feature is enabled, you can go back to the site settings page and change the rendition thumbnails to fit your needs (the out of box ones are pretty small). The server will automatically crop your images to the given size, but you can select images and choose how they are cropped for each rendition using the design tab in the ribbon. The server will then regenerate the rendition.